# Applying CSS to specific elements

Tags: css

I want to use `font-variant: small-caps` on the text of a `TD`

When I use the following it applies small-caps to everything within the TD

```
td {
font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

I only want to to apply to a TD when it contains text only, not the text relating to a `a href` or `input` etc.
Normally I'd do this with classes, but I don't have the option in the case.

I've tried:

```
td:not(a) {
font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

But that didn't seem to help.  Is this possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to overwrite the font-variant for children that are anchors etc.

```css
td {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

// overwrite children style at any level of nesting inside the cell

td a, td input {
  font-variant: initial;
}

// OR alternative syntax to simplify

td :is(a, input) {
  font-variant: initial;
}

// OR for immediate children

td > :is(a, input) {
  font-variant: initial;
}
```

The issue with your syntax `td:not(a)` is a cell element (td) cannot also be an anchor (a) element. You can try something similar by separating them (td and :not) with a space to select the children of the cell. It depends on your HTML structure and whether the text only cells have paragraphs where there are no anchors or inputs.

Comment: While `*` are usually frowned upon for performance reasons, in this case `td *` would also work if you want to keep the initial style for every child element (without having to list them in the `:is()`) and only style direct text-node children.

Answer (score 0):

My simplest suggestion would be:

- Any text content directly placed inside `td` would get `small-caps` style.
- Any child element of `td` that has a text content inside would get `initial` instead.

Below is a working code snippet. Should you need to include or exclude certain element types, you can further modify CSS selector to accommodate

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

td {
  font-variant: small-caps;
  padding: 16px;
}

td>* {
  font-variant: initial;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      All text as a direct child
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">All text inside hyperlink</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="name">
        <input id="name" name-"name" type="text" placeholder="text input..." >
      </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      Part of the text is <a href="#">inside hyperlink</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did this:

```css
td {font-variant: small-caps}
td * {font-variant:normal}
```

Then you should get the caps if text is directly within the td, but not caps for text in tags within the td.